# Bootstrap css main-container div falling below the side nav bar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have recently gotten a bootstrap 4 theme. I have been changing some files to work with flask. However I'm not able to figure out why my "main-container" div is falling below the nav bar when I change the page size to a more full size desktop browser size?

In the original bootstrap file the index.html file had the nav bar and page content on a single page. For flask I have moved most of this between three files layout.html, index.html and _navbar.html

I would like this to be on the right side of the nav bar when this is stretched to full desktop size but im not able to figure out what to change.

## layout.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Pipeline Project Management Bootstrap Theme</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="A project management Bootstrap theme by Medium Rare">
        <link href="static/img/favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gothic+A1" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="static/css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
    </head>

    <body>

       {%include 'includes/_navbar.html'%}

            {%block body%}


            {%endblock%}


        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/autosize.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/prism.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/draggable.bundle.legacy.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/swap-animation.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/dropzone.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/list.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/theme.js"></script>

    </body>

    <footer>
        <p><center><small><small>&copy; ME | &copy;ME </small></small></center></p>
    </footer>
</html>
```

## index.html

```
{%extends 'layout.html'%}

{%block body%}

<div class="main-container">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-lg-11 col-xl-9">
                <section class="py-4 py-lg-5">
                    <div class="mb-3 d-flex">
                        <img alt="Pipeline" src="static/img/logo-color.svg" class="avatar avatar-lg mr-1" />
                        <div>
                            <span class="badge badge-success">1.0</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h1 class="display-4 mb-3">Headline</h1>
                    <p class="lead">
                        Headline text 
                    </p>
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <div class="dropdown mr-3">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">Explore Pages</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="pages-app.html">App Pages</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="pages-utility.html">Utility Pages</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">View Components</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="components-bootstrap.html">Bootstrap Components</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="components-pipeline.html">Pipeline Components</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section class="py-4 py-lg-5">
                    <div class="carousel slide carousel-fade mb-5" data-ride="carousel">
                        <div class="carousel-inner overflow-visible">

                            <div class="carousel-item shadow-lg active">
                                <a href="pages-app.html">
                                    <img alt="Image" src="static/img/overview/nav-side-team.png" class="img-fluid rounded border" />
                                </a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="carousel-item shadow-lg ">
                                <a href="pages-app.html">
                                    <img alt="Image" src="static/img/overview/nav-side-project.png" class="img-fluid rounded border" />
                                </a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="carousel-item shadow-lg ">
                                <a href="pages-app.html">
                                    <img alt="Image" src="static/img/overview/nav-side-task.png" class="img-fluid rounded border" />
                                </a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="carousel-item shadow-lg ">
                                <a href="pages-app.html">
                                    <img alt="Image" src="static/img/overview/nav-side-kanban-board.png" class="img-fluid rounded border" />
                                </a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="carousel-item shadow-lg ">
                                <a href="pages-app.html">
                                    <img alt="Image" src="static/img/overview/nav-side-chat.png" class="img-fluid rounded border" />
                                </a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="carousel-item shadow-lg ">
                                <a href="pages-app.html">
                                    <img alt="Image" src="static/img/overview/nav-side-user.png" class="img-fluid rounded border" />
                                </a>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3">
                        <i class="material-icons text-primary mr-3 h1">supervised_user_circle</i>
                        <h2 class="h1 mb-0">Project Management Pages</h2>
                    </div>
                    <p class="lead">
                        Pipeline makes building project management interfaces simple with pages for teams, projects, tasks, kanban boards and more.
                    </p>
                    <a href="pages-app.html" class="mr-3">App Pages</a><a href="pages-utility.html" class="mr-3">Utility Pages</a>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{%endblock%}
```

## _navbar.html

```
[![<div class="layout layout-nav-side">
    <div class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark sticky-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
            <img alt="Pipeline" src="static/img/logo.svg" />
        </a>

        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="d-block d-lg-none ml-2">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <img alt="Image" src="static/img/avatar-male-4.jpg" class="avatar" />
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                        <a href="nav-side-user.html" class="dropdown-item">Profile</a>
                        <a href="utility-account-settings.html" class="dropdown-item">Account Settings</a>
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Log Out</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-column" id="navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav d-lg-block">

                <li class="nav-item">

                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Overview</a>

                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">

                    <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#submenu-2" aria-controls="submenu-2">Pages</a>
                    <div id="submenu-2" class="collapse">
                        <ul class="nav nav-small flex-column">

                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="pages-app.html">App Pages</a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="pages-utility.html">Utility Pages</a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="pages-layouts.html">Layouts</a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">

                    <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#submenu-3" aria-controls="submenu-3">Components</a>
                    <div id="submenu-3" class="collapse">
                        <ul class="nav nav-small flex-column">

                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="components-bootstrap.html">Bootstrap</a>
                            </li>

                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="components-pipeline.html">Pipeline</a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>

                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">

                    <a class="nav-link" href="documentation/index.html">Documentation</a>

                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">

                    <a class="nav-link" href="documentation/changelog.html">Changelog</a>

                </li>

            </ul>
            <hr>
            <div class="d-none d-lg-block w-100">
                <span class="text-small text-muted">Quick Links</span>
                <ul class="nav nav-small flex-column mt-2">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="nav-side-team.html" class="nav-link">Team Overview</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="nav-side-project.html" class="nav-link">Project</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="nav-side-task.html" class="nav-link">Single Task</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="nav-side-kanban-board.html" class="nav-link">Kanban Board</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <hr>
            </div>
            <div>
                <form>
                    <div class="input-group input-group-dark input-group-round">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text">
                                <i class="material-icons">search</i>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="search" class="form-control form-control-dark" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search app" aria-describedby="search-app">
                    </div>
                </form>
                <div class="dropdown mt-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="newContentButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Add New
                    </button>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="newContentButton">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Team</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Project</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Task</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="d-none d-lg-block">
            <div class="dropup">
                <a href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <img alt="Image" src="static/img/avatar-male-4.jpg" class="avatar" />
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a href="nav-side-user.html" class="dropdown-item">Profile</a>
                    <a href="utility-account-settings.html" class="dropdown-item">Account Settings</a>
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Log Out</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: site page showing div below nav bar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divs by default have `display: block` which makes them positioned on top of one another.

In order to position them properly you could either:

- Wrap them in a container div and use flexbox for positioning (Bootstrap row and columns),
- Use floats (Bootstrap float classes)

Below is an example of using floats to position divs.

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
}
.nav {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  float: left; 
  width: 70%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
  </div>
  <div class="clear">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry im not an expert on this. but would there be an example of what this would look like?

Comment: Edited the answer to add an example of floats.

Comment: Thanks this dose work, my only problem is now when the page is more in a mobile size the page is not formatted correctly.

Comment: You can use media queries to use css based on screen size or use bootstrap float classes: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/float/

Comment: You would have to use 2 classes on both navbar and content: "float-none float-lg-left"